# Using dark or light mode

Tags: javascript

what is the best way to incorporate something like this into my site? I've tried using plugins but I cant get it to work. Doesn't have to be fancy.

Does anyone have it or have used one in the past they can recommend? Otherwise, is there a way to code it using JavaScript?

Comment: you can write the css classes for the sections you want affected, then using an onclick event on a button replace the lightmode classes with darkmode ones.

You can use JavaScripts classlist feature.

Comment: Like what? I think you forgot upload your picture.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple approach that I've used several times:

- On the main html file, I load the default theme, for example the light one:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/light/theme.css" id="linkTheme" />
```

- Then, on the theme changer button/menu option, I change the CSS file of the above `link` to load the corresponding one, something like:

```
const handleToggleTheme = (dark) => {
    const lightUrl = "/themes/light/theme.css";
    const darkUrl = "/themes/dark/theme.css";

    if (dark) {
      document.getElementById('linkTheme').setAttribute('href', darkUrl);
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('linkTheme').setAttribute('href', lightUrl);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just set a button to trigger a boolean for example and based on its values, change the background-color of the items you want to change into dark mode.

Answer (score 0):

I personally used react context for this one, something like [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) (kinda perfect how they used theme as an example). You should study it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your framework, but if you use [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/), it has this option.
you can change palette type from light to dark and vice versa to achieve your requirements. [Take a look here](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#dark-mode).

But if you don't use any framework, you should make a css structure that has two classes, light and dark, have some properties like color and background color and etc., and when the toggle theme button clicked, you will change all your classes from light to dark for example, also you can use animation for the effects.

Answer (score 0):

There is a multiple solutions for this problem, if you are using a specific framework I suggest you check if there a way to do it with it, if you are not using any framework you still have multiple solutions and I suggest to create for each element you want to change his properties to dark mode another CSS class for each one, and with JavaScript create a function (that can call by a button on the html) that change all the element you want to those external classes, and if you click this button once again is reverse the function and make all the classes be with the original CSS classes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should help you to kickstart.

```
<html class="theme-light">
  <style>
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .theme-light {
      --color-primary: #0060df;
      --color-secondary: #fbfbfe;
      --color-accent: #fd6f53;
      --font-color: #000000;
    }

    .theme-dark {
      --color-primary: #17ed90;
      --color-secondary: #243133;
      --color-accent: #12cdea;
      --font-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: var(--color-secondary);
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .container h1 {
      color: var(--font-color);
    }

    .container button {
      color: var(--font-color);
      background: var(--color-primary);
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    // Set a Theme
    function setTheme(themeName) {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
      document.documentElement.className = themeName;
    }

    // Toggle From light and dark theme and Vice-Versa
    function toggleTheme() {
      if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark') {
        setTheme('theme-light');
      } else {
        setTheme('theme-dark');
      }
    }

    // Onload Theme
    (function() {
      if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark') {
        setTheme('theme-dark');
      } else {
        setTheme('theme-light');
      }
    })();
  </script>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Theme Switcher</h1>
      <button id="switch" onclick="toggleTheme()">Switch Theme</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You may also try this code from W3Schools.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_dark_mode